# How to level a ggplot2 histogram with two classes, with independent levels for each class?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Suppose I have this data:

```
xy <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4),c(rep('A',5),rep('B',3))))
```

So, when I type

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, fill = y)) +   
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), position = "dodge")
```

I get this graphic:

[image]

But I wanted to see the levels independently leveled, i.e., the red bars leveled to 0.2 and the blue bars leveled to 0.333. How can I achieve it?

Also, how can I set the y-axis to show the numbers in percentage instead of decimals?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try your code? can't get to anything here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the job. It uses ..density.. rather than ..count.., a rather ugly way to count the number of levels in the A/B factor column, and then the scales package to get the labels on the y axis

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, fill = y)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density../sum(..density..)*length(unique(xy$y)), group = y), position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to calculate everything in `ggplot`, you can first calculate the relative frequency and then use this value to plot it with `geom_col`. `preserve = "single"` preserves equal width of the bars:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dpylr)

xy <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4),
                 y = c(rep('A',5),rep('B',3)))

xy <- xy %>% 
  group_by(y, x) %>% 
  summarise(rel_freq = n()) %>% 
  mutate(rel_freq = rel_freq / n())

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = rel_freq, fill = y)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked with the example code but didn't work with my real data.
I did also a small experience, doing xy0 <- xy and re-pasting the  ggplot command, replacing "xy" by "xy0" in the first row. Strangely, the graphic was correctly generated but with decimal numbers (and no percentages) in the y axis.